# Most powerful test given a sample from a variable with known but not common (I think) distribution

Tags: self-study, hypothesis-testing

Let $X1,X2... Xn$ be a random sample from X and let X have the following pdf:

$g(\theta)xe^{\theta \frac {x^{2}}{2}}$ , $x$ from 0 to 1 and $g(\theta)$ is a normalized constant of the parameter $\theta > 0$.

The objective is to find the MP test for the problem:

$H0: \theta=0$

$H1: \theta=2$

I started by trying to find $g(\theta)$. Since the pdf is given, I used the fact that it integrates to 1 with respect to $x$ from 0 to 1. This gave me  $g(\theta)=\frac{\theta}{e^{\frac{\theta}{2}}-1}$

Now I am not sure how to continue.

Edit:

I just realized looking back at this problem that there seems to be some inconsistency between  the given and what is being asked. It clearly states in the given that $\theta>0$ but the null hypothesis is $\theta=0$. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Can you find a value of $g(\theta)$ to make the density function a valid one when $\theta=0$?

Comment: @Scortchi I do not follow. $g(\theta)$ is a function of $\theta$. It's value when $\theta=0$ is also 0. The density does exist at that point but is equal to 0 for all values of x.

Comment: Are all functions of zero zero?! What's $xe^{0\times \frac {x^{2}}{2}}$ simplify to? What's its integral from 0 to 1? What does $g(0)$ need to be to normalize it?

Comment: @Scortchi I'm sorry, I think I'm missing something basic here. What does it mean when one says "normalized constant"? I did not actually do anything about that in solving this. I took the integral $\int_0^1g(\theta)xe^{\theta \frac{x^2}{2}}dx$ and equated it to 1 to solve for $g(\theta)$.

Comment: Also, I get that not all functions of 0 are zero, but the function I got in solving for $g(\theta)$ which is $g(\theta)=\frac{\theta}{e^{\frac{\theta}{2}}-1}$ is zero when $\theta=0$. Again, I think I am missing something basic here.

Comment: Sorry, I see why you're saying that $g(0)=0$ now. It's not true though, $\frac{0}{e^{\frac{0}{2}}-1}=\frac{0}{0}$ is undefined. Find a separate solution for the case when $\theta=0$ (it's also the limit of your function $g(\theta)$ as $\theta\rightarrow 0$). (BTW it's "normalizing constant", & you've calculated it all right for $\theta>0$.)

Comment: Oh, I missed that. I thought it was 0/1. Ok I will work on it. I was also able to look up what "normalizing constant" means. Probably should have googled that before. Thanks.

Comment: So, provided that $\theta=0$ defines a valid density, the null hypothesis $\theta=0$ is still useful as an equivalent to the hypothesis that $\theta$ is arbitrarily close to zero.

Comment: Great.So $c(0)=2$ to make the function a pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So with the inputs I got from the comments, I now know that

$g(\theta)=\frac{\theta}{e^{\frac{\theta}{2}}-1}$  when $\theta>0$ and

$(g(\theta)$=2 when $\theta=0$

The likelihood function for the joint distribution of $x_i's$ is

$L(\theta|X)=c(\theta)^nx^ne^{\frac{\theta}{2}\sum x_i^2}$

Using Neyman-Pearson Lemma to test

$Ho: \theta=0$
$H1: \theta=2$

Reject Ho when:

$\frac{c(2)^nx^ne^{\frac{2}{2}\sum x_i^2}}{c(0)^nx^ne^{\frac{0}{2}\sum x_i^2}}>k$ which simplifies to $\frac{1}{(e-1)^n}e^{\sum x_i^2}>k$

After taking ln's and some more algebra:

Reject Ho when $\sum x_i^2>ln[(e-1)^nk]$

Where $\alpha=P_{\theta=0}(\sum x_i^2>ln[(e-1)^nk])$